# Site won't connect on word press migration

Tags: wordpress

So I am trying to migrate the local files to a server via cpanel and Filezilla. I went through and made a database and user.

I changed the information in the config.php file and uploaded to server but when I try and view in my domain name I get a ...

This site can’t be reached

testwp.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
Search Google for testwp
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I have been double checking the data in the config file but have no idea what could be causing this issue.

Any ideas? Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: So what is `testwp.com`, is that the actual live site domain name, or a local one you used during development?

Comment: Its my actual site domain I bought

Comment: Well then that has nothing to do with WordPress or your migration - the domain name itself can not be found by the DNS.

Comment: Is that because I bought it only 2 hours ago?

Comment: Yes, DNS changes take time to propagate. Give it a couple of hours. If it is not working after 24 hours, contact your hosting provider.